# Exact expression for the ground state energy in the 1D Bose-Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

I heard that Bose-Hubbard model is exactly solvable in 1D. What is then expression for the ground state energy $E_{0}(N, M, ...)$ as a function of total number of particles $N$, number of lattice sites $M$ and $J,U$? I would like to check how 
$$\frac{\partial E_0}{\partial N}\ \text{ and }\ \frac{\partial^2 E_0}{\partial N^2}$$
behave (after promoting $N$ to a continuous parameter).

Comment: It's the (Fermi) Hubbard model that is exactly solvable in 1D.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you heard wrong: there is no exact solution for the Bose-Hubbard model (BHM) in 1D. There are approximate solutions in the superfluid ($J\gg U$) and Mott insulator ($J\ll U$) limits, but neither works in the intermediate regime $J\sim U$. For $D>1$, mean-field theory is often used to interpolate between these limits, but is obviously an approximation. In 1D mean-field theory is unreliable but you have tensor network algorithms which allow near-exact simulation of a *truncated* BHM, i.e. where a limited number of bosons are allowed to occupy each site. Again, this is only an approximation.